# Media Source Extension on Firefox and IE

Tags: html, firefox, web-applications, internet-explorer-11, media-source

I'm creating a Audio Player with HTML5, using the MediaSource Object.

My code is similar to [MediaSource API Demo](https://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html)

But when executing the line

```
var ms = new MediaSource();
```

And exception is throwed on `Firefox` and `Internet Explorer`

```
ReferenceError: MediaSource is not defined
```

In [Firefox Support says](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1062326) that this feature is only enabled to `Youtube` and `Netflix`.

There is a way to handle this restriction?

In Chrome, I have not problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At time of writing, IE11 only has support when run on Windows 8.1 or above.

Firefox will only enable MSE when `about:config` param `media.mediasource.enabled = true` (this restriction will be removed eventually, once the FF implementation is globally stable). There is no way around this, so unless you are YouTube or Netflix, consider Firefox MSE as coming soon.

Comment: doesn't work after set  `media.mediasource.enabled` to true

Comment: Same here. media.mediasource.enabled doesn't make a difference. Have a look at this test: http://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has been lagging behind quite badly when it comes to MSE support in their browser. Firefox Nightly build however now seems to be pretty close to working properly. It still has to go through nightly build and beta phase before it's released to the public, so expect a few months.